# What program was used to create this visualization of a neighbor-joining tree?

Tags: bioinformatics, phylogenetics

I know there are many programs out there to visualize neighbor-joining trees in phylogenetics. I have a tree in Newick format. Does anyone recognize the features of this image as coming from a particular visualization program? I have tried several that may have produced this but with no success yet.

Note: I have to visually compare a new method's NJ tree with the result shown here, so that is why I really want to know exactly what program was used. This is not a question about software recommendation or opinions. Thanks! [image: NJ tree]

Comment: Honestly this looks like something someone put together by hand in illustrator (or a similar program)

Comment: Can't you just ask the author?